# Is there a way to disable this pop up?

Tags: visual-studio

I didn't use Visual Studio for a while and this started to show up now everytime it want's to autocomplete a line.

[image: the popup]

I tried looking in the settings but couldn't find a option to disable it. I just don't like it being there. My version of VS is 17.4.1

Comment: You want to disable just the popup or the whole autocomplete feature?

Comment: @PMF Only the popup